When introspecting authorization token auth information lost in Keycloak?
I am trying to get the permissions that is added for the user in my keycloak realm client. But i am not able to get the authorization information in introspection API.
Following are the steps I did to fetch the authorization information.
Step 1: Get users access token
To get the access token i am calling the API,
API:
{{base_path}}/realms/{{realm_name}}/protocol/openid-connect/token

Body:
client_id:democlient
client_secret:xxxxx
grant_type:password
username:testuser
password:123

and its response is,
{
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "session_state": "c3e7fddc-e38f-4519-b2c3-d6917e0ebae8",
    "scope": "email profile"
}

Step 2: Get authorization token
To get the authorization token i am calling the following API,
API:
{{base_path}}/realms/{{realm_name}}/protocol/openid-connect/token

Header:
Authorization:Bearer {{access_token}}

Body:
audience:democlient
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:uma-ticket

and the response is like,
{
    "upgraded": false,
    "access_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0
}

Step 3: Call Introspection with authorization token
Now called the introspection API with authorization token got from previous step,
API:
{{base_path}}/realms/{{realm_name}}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

Body:
client_id:democlient
client_secret:XXXXXXX
token:{{authorization_token}}


From this I got the introspection response without authorization key.
When I decode the JWT token from step 2 access_token I can see authorization key and all the permissions under it. But not available in introspection API response. So, what am i doing here wrong?
